# Calcular reta tangente pela coordenada do mouse/rato

Tags: java-processing

Estou querendo calcular a reta tangente aos pontos X e Y encontrados pelo mouse, limitando-se ao circulo desenhado... Só consegui desenvolver até a metade do programa. Alguém pode me salvar??

Estou desenvolvendo o programa no processing para fins academicos.

Segue meu código até agora:

```
void setup() {
    size(300, 300);
}

void draw() 
{
    int x = 0;  
    float nX = mouseX, nY = pow(mouseX,2)/300;

    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    rect(0,0,300,300); 

    fill(255,0,0);
    ellipse(nX,nY,10,10);
    text("  "+nX+" "+"/"+nY,nX,nY-5);

    fill(255,0,0);
    stroke(3);
    line(nX, 0, nX, 300);
    line(0, nY, 300, nY);

    while (x < 300) {
        fill(0);
        ellipse(x, x*x/300, 2, 2);
        x = x + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hum... pra mim não ficou muito claro o que você quer fazer. Qual é o efeito que deseja? O programa vai desenhar um círculo no primeiro clique do mouse, e então vai desenhar a tangente ao círculo *num novo ponto* sob o círculo em que o usuário clicar, é isso? Pode incluir na pergunta uma ilustração do resultado final?

Comment: pode nos mostrar com um desenho o resultado final que vc espera?

Answer (score 2):

Para calcular a reta tangente, precisamos calcular a derivada, que nos dará o coeficiente angular da reta:

[image]

Então desenhamos uma linha que passa pelo ponto do mouse e com o coeficiente angular igual a derivada aplicada nesse ponto.
Os dois pontos *A* e *B* que formam essa reta devem ter x = 0 e x = 300, respectivamente, e calculamos a altura usando a fórmula da reta tangente:

[image]

Sendo *P* o valor de x do mouse, fazendo as contas para os pontos, chegamos em:

[image]
[image]

Agora, finalmente... a programação:

Vendo que [image] é igual a `nX` e [image] é `nY`, e declarando `coef` como [image]...

```
float coef = nX / 150;
line(0, nY - coef * nX, 300 , nY + (300 - nX) * coef);
```

Pronto! Isso vai fazer a sua reta tangente!